# JavaFX: Red border for text field

Tags: text, javafx, field, border

I have a form with text fields and I want to give them a red border if I click on "save" but e.g. nothing was input in required fields, letters for the "birthday" field,... .

My files:
EditController.java, error.css

I already tried:

```
tfFirstName.getStyleClass().add("error");
```

, to remove it if they enter something valid:

```
tfFirstName.getStyleClass().remove("error");
```

and in the css:

```
.text-field.error {  
 -fx-border-color: red ;  
 -fx-border-width: 2px ;  
}
```

But it didn't change anything.

Surprisingly,

```
tfFirstName.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red ; -fx-border-width: 2px ;");
```

(and an empty string to get rid of it) works just fine but it isn't "pretty" if I want to add more to it later.

Does anyone know how to fix the css?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this it now works pefectly fine (it doesn't even need "setUpValidation"):

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    removeRed(tfFirstName);
    removeRed(tfLastName);
}

public void OKButtonClicked() {
    try{
        //also: call validation class here
        removeRed(tfFirstName);
        removeRed(tfLastName);
    } catch(ValidationException e) {
        setRed(tfFirstName);
        setRed(tfLastName);
    }

}

private void setRed(TextField tf) {
    ObservableList<String> styleClass = tf.getStyleClass();

    if(!styleClass.contains("tferror")) {
        styleClass.add("tferror");
    }
}


private void removeRed(TextField tf) {
    ObservableList<String> styleClass = tf.getStyleClass();
    styleClass.removeAll(Collections.singleton("tferror"));
}
```

And in the css I added the following (unfortunately it didn't change the border width with "-fx-border-width: 2px" anymore):

```
.tferror {  
     -fx-text-box-border: red ;
     -fx-focus-color: red ;   
}
```

Comment: Uh, `setUpValidation(...)` is just a utility method I wrote to make it add and remove the red border when the text field was empty/not empty. It actually has little to do with your question other than it demonstrates my solution works.

Answer (score 28):

Try

```
.text-field.error {
  -fx-text-box-border: red ;
  -fx-focus-color: red ;
}
```

The first sets the border color when it's not focussed, the second when it is focussed.

With this in the stylesheet `text-field-red-border.css`, the following example works:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ValidatingTextFieldExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        TextField nameTF = new TextField();
        TextField emailTF = new TextField();

        root.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 0);
        root.add(nameTF, 1, 0);
        root.add(new Label("Email:"), 0, 1);
        root.add(emailTF, 1, 1);

        setUpValidation(nameTF);
        setUpValidation(emailTF);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("text-field-red-border.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setUpValidation(final TextField tf) { 
        tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
                validate(tf);
            }

        });

        validate(tf);
    }

    private void validate(TextField tf) {
        ObservableList<String> styleClass = tf.getStyleClass();
        if (tf.getText().trim().length()==0) {
            if (! styleClass.contains("error")) {
                styleClass.add("error");
            }
        } else {
            // remove all occurrences:
            styleClass.removeAll(Collections.singleton("error"));                    
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

By the way, if you are using JavaFX 8, favor pseudoclasses over setting the class directly, as it's cleaner (you don't need all the ugly code checking that you only add the style class once and/or remove all occurrences of it) and more efficient. To set and unset the pseudoclass do:

```
final PseudoClass errorClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");

tfFirstName.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true); // or false to unset it
```

Then the css should be

```
.text-field:error {
  -fx-text-box-border: red ;
  -fx-focus-color: red ;
}
```

(Note the colon instead of the . between `-text-field` and `error`.)

Comment: It also looks like "tfFirstName.setStyle("");" only clears it right after it got set. If I want to clear it later, it'll keep the border.

Comment: You have to make sure you're not adding the style class multiple times (or when you clear it be sure to clear all occurrences). The style class is a list, so it can hold duplicate values.

Comment: Updated with complete example.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, it never shows the red border. The java & the css are in different packages (java: java/client, css: resources/gui) and the validation is done earlier. It only gets a red border if the validation throws an exception, so I split it up into 3 parts: "initialize" of the scene (= popup) calls "setUpValidation", in "catch" (exception) it calls "setRed()" (the if) and I call the "else" part when the "OK" button gets pressed to clear everything before validating. "setStyle" isn't pretty but at least it worked, is there a way to reset the textfields to default like that again?

Comment: Oh, and I forgot: I get the TextFields from my fxml file, so I simply do: "@FXML TextField tfFirstName" at the very beginning.

Comment: Did you run my code? If that doesn't work, which JDK version are you using and which platform are you on? It runs as expected for me on JDK  1.7.0_45.

Comment: No, I added the 2 methods and "setUpValidation(nameTF);" and it still didn't work. But I finally found the culprit: Looks like the textfield didn't use ".text-field:error", so I just changed it (see my other, "big" post) and now I works like a charm!

Comment: Worked fine for me. Wonder what is different on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the pseudoclasses, didn't know about those!

Answer (score 11):

When using the javafx8 moderna style, you can use this css to make the border similar to the 'on focus' blue border:

```
.text-input.error {
    -fx-focus-color: #d35244;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #d3524422;

    -fx-highlight-fill: -fx-accent;
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

add the css as classpath resource and load it using:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(<your css resource path>).toString());
```

then apply it to text fields using:

```
// add error class (red border)
textField.getStyleClass().add("error");
// remove error class (red border)
textField.getStyleClass().remove("error");
```

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned solution by James_D works perfectly fine ( but not for JAVAFX 8.0 ). James have already mentioned the code changes for JAVAFX 8.0, i just tried that and it works like a charm. Here is the changed version for JAVAFX 8.0, just incase someone needs a quick reference.All CREDIT GOES TO JAMES_D

```
import java.util.Collections;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ValidatingTextFieldExample extends Application {
private final PseudoClass errorClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    TextField nameTF = new TextField();
    TextField emailTF = new TextField();

    root.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 0);
    root.add(nameTF, 1, 0);
    root.add(new Label("Email:"), 0, 1);
    root.add(emailTF, 1, 1);

    setUpValidation(nameTF);
    setUpValidation(emailTF);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("text-field-red-border.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void setUpValidation(final TextField tf) { 
    tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                String oldValue, String newValue) {
            validate(tf);
        }

    });

    validate(tf);
}

private void validate(TextField tf) {
    ObservableList<String> styleClass = tf.getStyleClass();
    if (tf.getText().trim().length()==0) {
        tf.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
    }
    else{
        tf.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}