# TextField/Component Validation with Controls FX

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I'm trying to implement a textfield like this one :

[TextField Validation http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8329/FSht8P.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8329/FSht8P.png)

My goal is to identify if the text of the TextField is a `Double` or something else (then it appears in red).
I want to use **ControlsFX** to learn the library and to not edit the css, but it doesn't work very well, and I'm lost in the javadoc. Does anyone have an **example** or can help me **improve my code** ?

Here what I tried to do :

```
Validator<Double> checkTextField = new Validator<Double>() {

        @Override
        public ValidationResult apply(Control t, Double u) {
            ValidationResult vd = new ValidationResult();
            if(Double.valueOf(t.toString()) != null){
                vd.addErrorIf(t, "false", false);
            }
            return vd;

        }

    };


    ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
    validationSupport.registerValidator(latitudeTextField,  checkTextField/*Validator.createEmptyValidator("Text is required")*/);
    ValidationDecoration iconDecorator = new GraphicValidationDecoration();
    ValidationDecoration cssDecorator = new StyleClassValidationDecoration();
    ValidationDecoration compoundDecorator = new CompoundValidationDecoration(cssDecorator, iconDecorator);
    validationSupport.setValidationDecorator(compoundDecorator);
```

Comment: what happens? is there an error thrown or it's just doesnt work?

Comment: Well i'm not using the library correctly, I've got an exception because I compare string to double, but it's due to my lack of knowledge of ControlsFX

Comment: Why do you need ControlsFX control for this? This can be achieved using JavaFX TextField Control. Are there any special reasons for your choice?

Comment: Well Controls FX normally simplify it and I want to use the library for its other components, so I try to learn how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX: Red border for text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231610/javafx-red-border-for-text-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed make several mistakes. First you can have a look at the [ControlsFX Showcase](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/). There are always several code examples within their showcase.

Next your example expects the TextField to serve a Double to the Validator, but as you problably know the TextField itself only operates with Strings, so you will need a String Validator.

Then you try whatever control.toString() will print, which is most likely not the text it represents but some information about the control itself. What you want is the Text, which is currently shown in the textfield. For that you will not have to ask the control, since the text-value is already given to you in form of the value parameter 'u' in your case.

So what you want to do now is, you want to check, if the String could be parsed into a double. From the [Documention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) you can find a Regex to check if this is the case (don't know if there are any better regexes for your case).

So all together it could look like this:

```
    ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();

    Validator<String> validator = new Validator<String>()
    {
      @Override
      public ValidationResult apply( Control control, String value )
      {
        boolean condition =
            value != null
                ? !value
                    .matches(
                        "[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*" )
                : value == null;

        System.out.println( condition );

        return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf( control, "not a number", Severity.ERROR, condition );
      }
    };

    support.registerValidator( textfield, true, validator );
```

Comment: The validator is correct thanks, but how could obtain the window enlightened in red like in my picture using ControlsFX ? Because instead I got the default component with a red icon instead.

Comment: I always used the default-behavior, but I know you can also define your own Decorator with support.setValidationDecorator( ... ); The [StyleDecorator](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/validation/decoration/StyleClassValidationDecoration.html) seems to be the one you are looking for. Not sure, if you have to define your own .css classes to use it, or if there are already defaults with these borders.