# Is there an alternative to stacked if's for checking for many blank fields in javafx app?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, java-12

I'm new to java (and programming in general) and am learning by converting a basic spreadsheet into a javafx app.
For this I'm using:
Java & JavaFX 12
FXML & scenebuilder for the GUI

There are about 10 input fields and they can't be blank (the app crashes because getText seems to fail on blank fields).

I've written stacked if statements to check for blank fields and then print an error message if so, with a return to stop the process without crashing the app.

Switch statements don't seem to be any better than if statements.

Is there a way to do it with fewer lines of code?

```
package SteelDesign_BoltedConnection;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class mainController {

    //Header details
    @FXML   private TextField refNo;
    @FXML   private TextField jobDesc;
    @FXML   private TextField author;
    @FXML   private DatePicker date;

    //Design data
    @FXML   private TextField desShear;
    @FXML   private TextField boltSize;
    @FXML   private TextField boltGrade;
    @FXML   private TextField tensStrengthBolt;
    @FXML   private TextField noBolts;
    @FXML   private TextField shearPlanes;
    @FXML   private TextField edgeDist;
    @FXML   private TextField plyThick;
    @FXML   private TextField tensStrengthPly;

    //Constants
    @FXML   private TextField phiBolt;
    @FXML   private TextField phiPly;

    //Results - Bolt Shear
    @FXML   private TextField boltDesShear;
    @FXML   private TextField boltCap;
    @FXML   private TextField loadFactorBolt;

    //Results - Ply Shear & Bearing
    @FXML   private TextField plyDesShear;
    @FXML   private TextField plyCap;
    @FXML   private TextField loadFactorPly;

    //Output messages
    @FXML   private TextArea outputMsg;

    public void run(ActionEvent clickRun) {

        String outputMSG;

        //Check fields are populated
        if(desShear.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Design shear field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(boltSize.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Bolt size field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(tensStrengthBolt.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Bolt strength field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(noBolts.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Number of bolts field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(shearPlanes.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Number of shear planes field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(edgeDist.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Edge distance field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(plyThick.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Ply thickness field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(tensStrengthPly.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Ply strength field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(phiBolt.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Bolt phi factor field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }
        else if(phiPly.getText().isBlank()) {
            outputMSG = "Ply phi factor field is blank";
            outputMsg.setText(outputMSG);
            return;
        }

        //Get field values
        double desSHEAR = Double.parseDouble(desShear.getText());
        double boltSIZE = Double.parseDouble(boltSize.getText());
        double tensStengthBOLT = Double.parseDouble(tensStrengthBolt.getText());
        double noBOLTS = Double.parseDouble(noBolts.getText());
        double shearPLANES = Double.parseDouble(shearPlanes.getText());
        double edgeDIST = Double.parseDouble(edgeDist.getText());
        double plyTHICK = Double.parseDouble(plyThick.getText());
        double tensStrengthPLY = Double.parseDouble(tensStrengthPly.getText());
        double phiBOLT = Double.parseDouble(phiBolt.getText());
        double phiPLY = Double.parseDouble(phiPly.getText());

        //Bolt shear calculation


        }

}
```

Comment: Validation using ControlsFX? take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607080/textfield-component-validation-with-controls-fx)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (package name and class name are still violating them ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way or another you need to associate one field with one string. This requires you to add some code for each of the `TextField`s, whether that's setting the `userData` in the fxml or storing the compination of `TextField` and `String` in a suitable data structure in the controller's `initialize` method.

Such a data structure could be `LinkedHashMap`:

```
private final Map<TextField, String> fieldStrings = new LinkedHashMap<>();

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    fieldStrings.put(desShear, "Design shear");
    fieldStrings.put(boltSize, "Bolt size");
    fieldStrings.put(tensStrengthBolt, "Bolt strength");
    fieldStrings.put(noBolts, "Number of bolts");
    fieldStrings.put(shearPlanes, "Number of shear planes");
    fieldStrings.put(edgeDist, "Edge distance");
    fieldStrings.put(plyThick, "Ply thickness");
    fieldStrings.put(tensStrengthPly, "Ply strength");
    fieldStrings.put(phiBolt, "Bolt phi factor");
    fieldStrings.put(phiPly, "Ply phi factor");
}

private double getFieldValue(TextField field) {
    return Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
}

public void run(ActionEvent clickRun) {

    String errorField = fieldStrings.entrySet().stream()
                                     .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getText().isBlank())
                                     .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                                     .findFirst().orElse(null);

    if (errorField != null) {
        outputMsg.setText(errorField + " field is blank");
        return;
    }

    //Get field values
    double desSHEAR = getFieldValue(desShear);
    double boltSIZE = getFieldValue(boltSize);
    double tensStengthBOLT = getFieldValue(tensStrengthBolt);
    double noBOLTS = getFieldValue(noBolts);
    double shearPLANES = getFieldValue(shearPlanes);
    double edgeDIST = getFieldValue(edgeDist);
    double plyTHICK = getFieldValue(plyThick);
    double tensStrengthPLY = getFieldValue(tensStrengthPly);
    double phiBOLT = getFieldValue(phiBolt);
    double phiPLY = getFieldValue(phiPly);


    //Bolt shear calculation


}
```

Comment: That looks good - I've not used a lot of the code you written, but it is much more economical than mine for lines of code.  Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: I was expecting the `initialize` method to declare the text fields (eg. desShear).  But I actually still need to put them in ahead of `initialize`, right?  ie. `@FXML private TextField desShear;` and `@FXML private TextField boltSize;`, etc. still need to be listed as per my original post.  If I don't, it tells me they "cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: `FXMLLoader` injects objects created for elements with the `fx:id` attribute to non-`static` fields of the controller instance. the only thing that `initialize` is responsible for is doing any "once per scene" initialisations that can be done with the values of those fields and any data accessible in the controller instance at that time... (So that's a ***yes***.)

Comment: Cool thanks, just making sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: at the end of the day, you'll probably need to do more involved validation - so you might want to jump for a semantic solution by using a) a model that contains the data and guards itself against invalid input and b) textFormatters on the fields that enforce the constraints.